# Type hint nominal inheritence bug Expected type 'Tuple[A]', got 'Tuple[B, ...]' instead

Tags: python, inheritance, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

Consider the following :

```py
from typing import Tuple


class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()


def foo() -> Tuple[A]:
    return tuple([B()])


foo()
```

PyCharm gives a warning:

> `Expected type 'Tuple[A]', got 'Tuple[B, ...]' instead`

on `tuple([B()])`.

Since `B` "is a" `A`, this is annoying and wrong.

How to best deal with this?

Comment: Mypy also complains about it.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your `return` statement:

```
return tuple([B()])
```

Let's unpack that a bit.

`B()` has type `B`, of course.

`[B()]` is a list, with a single element of type `B`. The static type of this list is deduced as `list[B]`, a list of `B` instances.

Now look at `tuple([B()])`. You're calling `tuple` with a single argument of static type `list[B]`. If you call `tuple` with an argument of static type `list[B]`, the static type of the result is `tuple[B, ...]`.

It's not `tuple[A]`, or even `tuple[B]`. The static type of `[B()]` doesn't contain any length information, so the type of the tuple doesn't contain any length information either. It's just a tuple containing some number of `B` instances.

---

The problem is, you went through a list. You need to not do that. Make a tuple directly:

```
return (B(),)
```

Then static analyzers can directly see that this is a tuple with a single element of type `B`, in a context where a `tuple[A]` is expected, and deduce that the tuple can and should be treated as a `tuple[A]`.

Comment: The parenthesis are redundant in your code snippet.

Comment: @bad_coder: They may be technically unnecessary, but they make the tuple more obvious. It's easier to miss a single trailing comma without parentheses.

Comment: This isn't a mypy question but a PyCharm linter question.

Comment: @bad_coder: Removed explicit mypy reference.

Comment: Let me quote you: *"The static type of [B()] doesn't contain any length information,"* this statement is incorrect, the type of the values in a list is inherently arbitrary-length since there's no way to hint that it's fixed length.

Answer (score 1):

> How to best deal with this?

The easiest way is returning a literal declaration instead of using a constructor (the syntax is also more concise), if you write the `return` as:

```py
def foo() -> Tuple[A]:
    return B(),
```

But you can also use the constructor provided it's initialized from a single element fixed length collection, the PyCharm linter won't complaint, for example:

```py
def foo() -> Tuple[A]:
    return tuple((B(),))
```

Looking carefully at the error message:

> `got 'Tuple[B, ...]'`

The ellipsis `...` here implies you are returning an arbitrary length tuple (the static type checker infers this because you initialize the tuple using a list), while the type hint `-> Tuple[A]` requires a fixed length single element tuple, see:

> [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-typing-module)
>
> - Tuple, used by listing the element types, for example `Tuple[int, int, str]`. The empty tuple can be typed as `Tuple[()]`. Arbitrary-length homogeneous tuples can be expressed using one type and ellipsis, for example `Tuple[int, ...]`. (The `...` here are part of the syntax, a literal ellipsis.)

I tested this both with Python 3.8 and Python 3.9 (notice that's the version when [`typing.Tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) was deprecated in favor of using parametrized builtins for type hints.)